# How to avoid browser caching of assets/vendor.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have Ember-CLI application and in index.html there is lines:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
<script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
```

And browser caches this files. And I want to add ?v=:version-no, I want to do generation of version during execution of `ember build`.

How can I add this feature into `ember build`?

Comment: Ember cli comes loaded with livereload, any change you make during development will be reflected on the browser, if you are building for deployment then @user1156168 's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

build application with `ember build --environment=production`

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well, but my problem is that when I try to build with the production environment, some of my dependencies are not found (ember-pikaday) for one. And I have no idea where to look for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ember production builds come with fingerprinting enabled by default. If you want you can turn this on by setting it to true in your **ember-cli-build.js** file.

This will generate automatic fingerprints for you for test builds. This will add a fingerprint to file for you e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor-1bcb3fe1589b69c2436b45465444058d.css">
```

Here is an example:

```
// ember-cli-build.js
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    enabled: true
  }
});
```

You will find more help if you search for Ember fingerprinting. Here is a helpful page with some more details: http://ember-cli-deploy.com/docs/v0.4.x/fingerprinting-options-and-staging-environments/